# Is there another cheering phase to say rather than 頑張って？

Tags: phrase-requests

I usually followed several Japanese actors on SNS.

Sometime when they have an audition, people usually cheer them by commenting "頑張って/頑張ってください".

However, I learned that some of them doesn't really like this because they are already doing their best.

I was wondering if there are any other sentences that I can use? I wanna say good luck as well, but the english equivalent is also 頑張って...

The only thing I came up with it is 応援してるよ。

Comment: Where did you hear that people don't like to be told 頑張ってください?

Comment: That is often heard actually.  OP is correct on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could say:

・「ファイト！」

・「気楽{きらく}にね！」

・「うまくいきますように！」

・「しっかりね！」

・「応援{おうえん}してま～す！」

・「（ご）成功{せいこう}を祈{いの}ってます！♡」

I could go all night long with this, but as you seem to know, none of these will ever be nearly as common as the plain ol' 「がんばって」.

Answer (score 1):

Probably 御武運{ごぶうん｝を。also works. You can also see the character signifies "good luck" in the sentence. I guess in English "finger crossed" or something.